# tsql EXEC AT server

Tags: sql-server, ibm-midrange, db2-400

**If I run:**

```
exec('myString') at [myserver]
```

my selection works correctly

**If I do:**

```
declare @mystring nvarchar(max) = 'myString'
exec(@mystring) at [myserver]
```

> (Righe interessate: 2)
>   OLE DB provider "IBMDASQL" for linked server "myserver" returned message "SQL0104: Token '' non valido. Token validi: ( CL END GET SET CALL DROP FREE HOLD LOCK OPEN WITH ALTER BEGIN.
>   Causa  . . . : È stato rilevato un errore di sintassi sul token ''. Il token '' non è valido.  Un elenco parziale dei token validi è ( CL END GET SET CALL DROP FREE HOLD LOCK OPEN WITH ALTER BEGIN.  Questo elenco presuppone che l'istruzione sia corretta fino al token.  È possibile che l'errore sia precedente nell'istruzione, ,ma la sintassi dell'istruzione sembrava valida fino a questo punto. Correzione  . . : Effettuare almeno una delle seguenti operazioni e ripetere: -- Verificare l'istruzione SQL nell'area del token ''. Correggere l'istruzione. L'errore potrebbe essere una virgola o apici mancanti, una parola scritta in modo scorretto oppure potrebbe essere relativo all'ordine delle clausole. -- Se il token di errore è , correggere l'istruzione SQL perché non termina con una clausola valida.".
>
> (Righe interessate: 0)
>   Messaggio 7215, livello 17, stato 1, riga 308
>   Could not execute statement on remote server 'myserver'.

Here is the english version of SQL0104

> Message ID . . . . . . . . . :   SQL0104
>   Message file . . . . . . . . :   QSQLMSG
>     Library  . . . . . . . . . :     QSYS
>
> Message . . . . :   Token &1 was not valid. Valid tokens: ( CL END GET SET CALL DROP FREE HOLD LOCK OPEN WITH ALTER BEGIN.
>   Cause . . . . . :   A syntax error was detected at token ''.  Token '' is not 
>     a valid token.  A partial list of valid tokens is ( CL END GET SET CALL DROP FREE HOLD LOCK OPEN WITH ALTER BEGIN.  This list assumes that the statement is correct up to the token.  The error may be earlier in 
>     the statement, but the syntax of the statement appears to be valid up to
>     this point.
>   Recovery  . . . :   Do one or more of the following and try the request again:
>       -- Verify the SQL statement in the area of the token ''. Correct the
>     statement.  The error could be a missing comma or quotation mark, it could
>     be a misspelled word, or it could be related to the order of clauses.
>       -- If the error token is , correct the SQL statement
>     because it does not end with a valid clause.

Comment: Either need an English error translation or we should get this over to the spanish side of stack exchange.

Comment: And we probably need to see the actual SQL string.

Comment: memm077 - mind sharing what 'mystring' is?

Comment: @Twelfth - It's definitely not Spanish. Looks like Italian to me.

Comment: @JohnY - Ha, I shoulda recognized that.   whoops.   In any case, the error is a syntax problem with whatever "'myString'" is.  er..actually I think if you tried to execute 'mystring' it would give the error "it does not end with a valid clause"

Comment: Scusate la traduzione, si è italiano! Il problema è che se eseguo exec della stringa, il comando funziona se, lo eseguo su variabile nvarchar (che contiene la stessa identica stringa), va in errore. Quello sopra è solo un esempio ovviamente, 'myString' = Select ....